# Azure DevOps Release pipeline failing because of library "azureml-inference-server-http"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have configured a `Build (CI)` and `Release (CD)` Pipeline in `Azure DevOps` for deploying a Machine Learning model in `AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service)`.

Build pipeline ran successfully, but while running Release Pipeline I am getting below error, even though `azureml-inference-server-http` library is mentioned in `install_requirements.sh`.

```
A required package azureml-inference-server-http is missing. Please install azureml-inference-server-http before trying again
```

Logs from the deployed endpoint in AKS
[image]

**install_requirements.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
python --version
pip install azure-cli --force-reinstall
pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk[cli]
pip install azureml-inference-server-http
```

**Release pipeline steps**
[image]

**Runtime Info**

Build Pipeline: ubuntu-20.04, Python 3.8

Release Pipeline: ubuntu-20.04, Python 3.8